# Python cannot import name client

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload files to dropbox using the dropbox api in python. I cannot get dropbox to work.

```
import dropbox
```

or

```
from dropbox import client, rest, session
```

both give me the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name client

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the dropbox api using pip. And I have tried several examples. What is the issue?

Comment: Do you have any scripts or folders called `dropbox` or `dropbox.py` in the current folder?

Comment: Strange, works for me. Was there any warning/error during the pip installation? Are you using python2?

Comment: do you have any other client module in your path, or a folder with that name and the init py inside? You can check that with python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'. Also, what do you have /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dropbox/__init__.pyc or something similar?

Comment: Another suggestion for debugging this: just before the failing line, add "import dropbox; print dropbox" .  That should reveal if something else is imported as dropbox (which I suspect it is).